# Using Docker Environment Variable inside of Java

Tags: docker, spring-boot, mariadb

I am creating a Spring Boot application that sits inside of a Docker container. On the same server as the Spring Boot's container, is a second Docker container that holds a MariaDB which the Spring Boot app must be able to access.

When running the MariaDB container, and the Spring Boot app on the host machine, the app gains access to the database through "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/fi?user=username&password=somepassword". I understand when the app is deployed as a container, it cannot be done this way. I have successfully "linked" the two containers by including "--link mariadb:db" in the run statement, where mariadb is the name of the MariaDB container.

When the app container is running, I can ping the MariaDB container by running the command "ping mariadb". My question is, how would I use the mariadb environment variable inside of my Java file to call the database in the mariadb container?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you refer to `localhost` instead of `mariadb` in your connection url.

When you link a docker container it will automatically get the proper entry added in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: So the connection url should be jdbc:mariadb://mariadb:3306/fi?user=username&password=somePassword ??

Comment: Yes if the link name is mariadb

Comment: @dFrancisco great! You can press the checkbox to the left of the answer to mark the answer as correct